# set array values in to a text area in java

Tags: java, arraylist

i want to set an array list value in to a text area.
this is my code,

```
ArrayList<String> phone_numberArray = db.getNumberSms();

        for(int i=0; i<phone_numberArray.size(); i++){
          jtext_area.addElement(phone_numberArray.get(i));
        }
```

this code getting errors.
some one help me please....

Comment: What is the `type` of jtext_area?

Comment: @gotomanners it's String type

Comment: @oliholz solution is what you need!

Answer (score 2):

I assume `jtext_area` is an instance of [`JTextArea`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html) , I don't see any `addElement()` in that class, You might be looking for [`append()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html#append%28java.lang.String%29)

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
for(String number : db.getNumberSms()) {
    jtext_area.append(number);
}
```