# Looping through a Java array and append() to a TextArea

Tags: java, textarea

After more than a couple of days I am still unable to populate a text area by going through an array as I can in other languages. I have tried Google, YouTube, stackoverflow, and others and I am still unable to use any examples to help me do this. I have also referenced Java texts. Here is exactly what I am trying to do:

```
public void getDrinks() {
    //System.out.println(theDrinks[arrayCount].toString());

    for(int i=0; i<arrayCount; i++) {
        area.append(theDrinks[i].toString());
    }
}
```

This code works in other languages but something is wrong with the way I am using the `TextArea` or the array because I am getting a null pointer. I would love to paste the entire program, but that is not working either. This is the only part that will even remotely paste correctly. Please help me if you can.

Comment: What is `arrayCount`? What is `theDrinks`?  You have to give us something to work with.

Comment: Also, is `area` guaranteed to be initialized before `getDrinks()` is called?

Comment: arrayCount is the number of string objects in the array which is 3, theDrinks is the actual array, area is initialized before getDrinks() is called, I wish I could figure out how to post the entire program its not long any tips?

Comment: You should get a book on basic Java programming. Here's one - http://www.amazon.com/Effective-Java-2nd-Joshua-Bloch/dp/0321356683.

Comment: `area` is null or `theDrinks` contains a `null` entry (then `toString()` fail). You can easily find out the problem using a debugger.

Comment: ok so I completely started over. The null pointer stems from the JTextArea I am trying to append(). How can I loop through an array and append a text area from another class?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6409924/set-array-values-in-to-a-text-area-in-java

Answer (score 2):

You do not, in general, want to use a variable like `arrayCount` when you can help it.  A better version is this:

```
public void getDrinks() {
    for(int i = 0; i < theDrinks.length; i++)
        area.append(theDrinks[i].toString());
}
```

When doing this, it is important to make sure that `area` has been instantiated already (i.e. it is not `null`).

If I were implementing this, I would use Java's foreach construct instead, as I find it's a bit more expressive.  The following code assumes that `theDrinks` is an array of `Drink` objects.

```
public void getDrinks() {
    if(area != null) {
        for(Drink drink : theDrinks) {
            area.append(drink.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't way whay your specific problem can be without more code but here some java code that works.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.TextArea;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Driver {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // 1. Create the frame.
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("FrameDemo");

        // 2. Optional: What happens when the frame closes?
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        // 3. Create components and put them in the frame.
        // ...create emptyLabel...

        TextArea area = new TextArea("Area");
        frame.getContentPane().add(area, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        // 4. Size the frame.
        frame.pack();

        // 5. Show it.
        frame.setVisible(true);

        String[] drinks = {"Drink1","Drink2"};
        getDrinks(area, drinks);
    }

    public static void getDrinks(TextArea area, String[] theDrinks) {
        // System.out.println(theDrinks[arrayCount].toString());

        for (String drink : theDrinks) {

            area.append(drink.toString());

        }

    }

}
```